# Двоичное число (Int to binary)

Tags: c++

В C++ можно записать двоичное число:
`int x = 0b11001;`

У меня это двоичное число хранится как простое десятичное число:

`int x = 11001;`

Как его можно перевести в двоичное, ведь способ:

`int binary = 0bx;`

Работать не будет.

Нужно двоичное значение конвертировать в UTF-8:

`char c[5] = { 0,0,0,0,0 }; // arba unsigned char`

```
c[0] = 0b11100010; // (dec - 226, hex - e2 (0xe2))
c[1] = 0b10011000; // (dec - 152, hex - 98 (0x98))
c[2] = 0b10111010; // (dec - 186, hex - ba (0xba))
```

Это работает, но мне нужно получить двоичное число, путём конвертации из десятичного. Приставку 0b можно как нибудь дописать к переменной?

Comment: хранится оно как раз в двоичном виде. а вот на отображение (`cout`, например) вы видете десятичный вид числа. напишите что именно вы хотите сделать и переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Если вы хотите это число увидеть как двоичное, то это куда то нужно выводить(в консоль, в файл), то есть выводить нужно строковое представление числа:   **std::to_string(x)**. (или интересует сама реализация этой функции?..) Но если не это вы хотите, то тогда формулируйте вопрос доходчиво

Comment: Мне нужно получить из двоичного значения UTF-8 символ. Исправил вопрос, может будет понятнее

Comment: `int powerOfTwo = 1; int result = 0; while (x) {result += x % 10 * powerOfTwo; powerOfTwo *= 2; x /= 10;}`

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас есть код символа (Unicode) и вы хотите получить этот символ в *кодировке utf-8*? Если так, то [вот тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) описан алгоритм кодирования

Answer (score 0):

Нет, приставку к переменной дописать не получится, тем более число 11001 не является двоичным (в данном случае), а дестичным.

```
int mask = 1, res = 0, x = 11001;
while(x) {
    if(x % 10)
        res += mask;
    x /= 10;
    mask <<= 1;
}
```